# Отсутствует страница проверки логина и пароля

Tags: java, spring

отсутствует страница проверки логина и пароля.
использую Spring security

```
login.jsp
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/login" />">

<table>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><spring:message code="label.login" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><spring:message code="label.password" /></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><spring:message code="label.remember" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Login" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
```

так же вместо /login  использовал j_spring_security_check 
и так и так выдает ошибку 404 
в чем может быть дело

security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http >
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/error403.jsp"/>
    <!--<intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="permitAll" />-->
    <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/add*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/contact.jsp" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/delete/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/login.jsp"
                authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=1" />
    <!--<logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index" />-->
    <logout logout-url="/logout" />

    <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
    <remember-me />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="pass" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="user1" password="1111" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="user2" password="2222" disabled="true" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- Описание корневого контейнера, разделяемого всеми сервлетами и фильтрами -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Создаёт контейнер Spring, разделяемый всеми сервлетами и фильтрами -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Базовый сервлет, обрабатывает все запросы к приложению -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Фильтр для перекодировки в utf8 -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

вот видно на картинке, что есть такая страница login но при переходе на него с браузер выдает ошибку 404 отсутствует страница, 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: method=POST, вы пробовали на него послать ПОСТ запрос ?
Есть ли ответ и какой ?

Comment: Настройку спринг секурити добавьте.

Comment: @vartlok добавил

Comment: @4bal0v вы имеете ввиду пост запрос на login.jsp, но мне надо отправить запрос на login или  j_spring_security_check обе эти страницы выдают ошибку 404

Comment: @JTan попробуйте добавить в конфигурацию `form-login` `login-processing-url="/login"`

Comment: @vartlok такая же ошибка, 404

Comment: @JTan окей, у меня еще одна идея. Вы наверняка используете Spring MVC? Если так, то проверьте что диспатчер у вас замаплен на `/` а не на `/*` Если и это не поможет, то надо включать все логи и смотреть что в них пишется, почему 404.

Comment: @vartlok     @RequestMapping("/") здесь установлен на /, Это находится в классе, это в контроллере, правильно ли я сделал, и еще как мне включить логи, я первый раз делаю со spring по этой ссылке все сделано http://habrahabr.ru/post/111102/

Comment: Я про web.xml а не про маппинг ваших контроллеров

Comment: @vartlok добавил в вопрос web.xml.

Comment: Прочитайте мой ответ ниже, у вас неправильные параметры j_username и j_password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="login-link-container">
    <sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Sign In" onClick='location.href="/login"'>
        </p>
    </sec:authorize>
    <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
        <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>
        <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        </form>
    </sec:authorize>
</div>
```

Так настроен сам переход на страницу стандартного логина, который возможен с помощью Spring Security.

Настройки Security стандартные (использовал Java-config):

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
    http.sessionManagement()
        .invalidSessionUrl("/");
    http.formLogin();
    http.rememberMe();
    http.logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    http.logout().logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout");
    http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
```

Так выглядит индивидуализрованная форма:

```
<form action="/j_spring_security_check" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <input placeholder='Username' name="j_username" type='text'>
        <input placeholder='Password' name="j_password" type='password'>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Дело  даже не в переменных, это названия переменных для spring security 3 а я использую 4 версию, здесь описаны переменные, http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html но все же я сделал форму с вашими переменными и указал action="/j_spring_security_check" и login тоже использовал  такая же ошибка страница отсутствует, добавил картнику в вопрос посмотрите, login есть а вот j_spring_security_check красным подсвечивает

Comment: Сейчас такая вот проблема при отправке данных на login выдает ошибкуHTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired? но бывает и так  Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Comment: Скажите, в данный момент что у вас стоит в form-login в login-page, на какой URL вы уходите, по ссылке и что прописано. Потому что в этот момент указывается где находится ваша страница, по какому адресу.

Comment: Для теста, попробуйте воспользоваться обычной формой, которую spring предлагает написав <form-login />

Comment: поменял в security.xml на default-target-url="/index" это страница куда переадресовывается после удачного логина  а так же отключил csrf         <csrf disabled="true"/>
сейчас так работает

Comment: если включить  csrf выдает ошибку Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN